# Efficiency of Ruby code: hash of month + frequency into formatted sorted array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, date, hash

I've hacked up some code that fulfills its purpose but it feels very clunky/inefficient. From a table of many entries, each has a month + year string associated with it: "September 2016" etc. From these I create a chronologically ordered array of months and their frequencies to be used in a dropdown selection form: ['Novemeber 2016 (5)', 'September 2016 (5)'].

```
@months = []

banana = Post.pluck(:month)
#array of all months posted in, eg ['September 2016', 'July 2017', etc

strawberry = banana.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|key,hash| hash[key] += 1}
#hash of unique month + frequency

strawberry.each { |k, v| strawberry[k] = "(#{v.to_s})" } 
#value into string with brackets

pineapple = (strawberry.sort_by { |k,_| Date.strptime(k,"%b %Y") }).reverse 
#sorts into array of months ordered by most recent

pineapple.each { |month, frequency| @months.push("#{month}" + " " + "#{frequency}") }
#array of formatted months + frequency, eg ['July 2017 (5)', 'September 2016 (5)']
```

I was hoping some of the Ruby gurus here could advise me in some ways to improve this code. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['September 2016', 'July 2017', 'September 2016', 'July 2017']
  .group_by { |e| e } # .group_by(&:itself) since Ruby2.3
  .sort_by { |k, _| Date.parse(k) }
  .reverse
  .map { |k, v| "#{k} (#{v.count})" }

#⇒ [
#  [0] "July 2017 (2)",
#  [1] "September 2016 (2)"
# ]
```